# Не работают три последних :hover в списке

Tags: html, css

Имеется следующий кусок кода в HTML и его стилизация на CSS:

```css
.footer__social {
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer__fb:hover {color: #09a3f0};
.footer__tw:hover {color: #a4dcf8};
.footer__ins:hover {color: #e53e28};
.footer__drib:hover {color: #df7e44};
```

```html
<div class="footer__social">
    <ul class="social__list">
        <li><a class="footer__fb" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer__tw" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer__ins" href="#">Instagram</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer__drib" href="#">Dribble</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что первый hover прекрасно работает, а оставшиеся три последних нет. Вроде уже все перепроверил по 10 раз, не пойму в чем причина.

Comment: в точках с запятой не в тех местах

Comment: потому что `;` не должны стоять там где Вы их поставили. уберите и всё заработает

Comment: Стыд и позор мне. Не часто пишу CSS-правила в одну строчку, вот и не заметил как точку с запятой поставил после закрывающей фигурной скобки...Спасибо всем ответившим)

Answer (score 1):

лишнее в css просто не суйте :) (я про `;`)

```css
.footer__social {
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer__fb:hover {color: #09a3f0;}
.footer__tw:hover {color: #a4dcf8;}
.footer__ins:hover {color: #e53e28;}
.footer__drib:hover {color: #df7e44;}
```

```html
<div class="footer__social">
    <ul class="social__list">
        <li><a class="footer__fb" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer__tw" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer__ins" href="#">Instagram</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer__drib" href="#">Dribble</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```